# Send a JSON object from memory by FTP

Tags: python, scrapy, ftp, scrapyd

i've deployed a spider to scrapyd. in development the spider was writing a file to disk.
deployed no file is produced. I believe it is a permission problem. i'm looking to ftp the data out. so, solution 1 would be not to write a file at all. is there a way to take a list of dict objects and ftp them out without creating a file first? Or 2: is a temp file a viable option & would the permissions be easier on that. or 3, can i give the scrapyd daemon more privileges?

thanks,

jim

mOutput = dict()
dict_list = []
for units in tableRows:

```
            mOutput = {
                'model': units.xpath(".//td[1]/text()").get().replace('\xa0',''), 
                'modelName': units.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").get(),
                'oct': units.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").get(),
                'nov': units.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").get(),
                'dec': units.xpath(".//td[5]/text()").get(),
                'jan': units.xpath(".//td[6]/text()").get(),
                'feb': units.xpath(".//td[7]/text()").get(),
                'mar': units.xpath(".//td[8]/text()").get(),
                'apr': units.xpath(".//td[9]/text()").get(),
                'may': units.xpath(".//td[10]/text()").get(),
                'jun': units.xpath(".//td[11]/text()").get(),
                'july': units.xpath(".//td[12]/text()").get(),
                'total': units.xpath(".//td[14]/text()").get(),
                'shipped': units.xpath(".//td[14]/text()").get()                   
            } 
            dict_list.append(mOutput)
        
        objToFTP = json.dumps(dict_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

this method accepts objToFTP as input. so, i no longer need to create a f file locally. be sure to add these imports:

import io,
from ftplib import FTP

```
def sendFile(self,data):
        with FTP('192.168.0.101') as ftp:
            ftp.login()
            bio = io.BytesIO()
            bio.write(data.encode())
            bio.seek(0)  # move to beginning of file
            ftp.storbinary('STOR data.json', bio)                                            
            ftp.quit() #probably don't neeed this
```